# INIT CPANEL DEL CMS BOLT

Tags: cms

Estimados buenas a todos, Consulta tengo un problema. la  carga de la pagina principal de mi Cpanel del CMS-BOLT no responde, Mis claves de acceso son las correctas. El CMS-BOLT  esta asociado con phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

El Cpanel no tiene que ver con Bolt, el cpanel es para instalar y administrar la configuracion del servidor como bases de datos, version de php o pyhton, backups, ftp y archivos no para el cms y phpmyadmin es para administrar y editar las bases de datos de forma grafica, te recomiendo ponerte en contacto con tu hosting y reportar el problema, o si es un servidor propio reinicialo

Comment: Si te refieres a la pagina de login prueba en ver que se encuentren todos los archivos necesarios para su funcionamiento desde ftp o el administrador de archivos si no puede ser que te haigan hackeado si fue asi. restaura una copia de seguridad de tu sitio y si no la tienes o no la hiciste es momento de empezar a hacerlas, asi se aprende o almenos asi tambien aprendi yo =( y si vuelve a pazar te recomiendo cambiar de hosting a uno de mejor calidad o usar una contraseña muy robusta en tu cpanel o un gestor de contraseñas que algunos ya tienen incluidos generadores de contraseñas robustas